# Problema com um modal

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom estou com um problema com esse modal, ele abre assim q entra no index.php, porém caso eu mude a pagina por ex para duvidas.php e clique para voltar no index.php o alert aparece novamente, tem como configurar para o alert só aparecer uma vez e só aparecer dnv se a pessoa fechar a aba?

codigo :

```
<script>
function fechaAviso(){
    document.querySelector("#tela").style.display = "none";
    // jquery abaixo
    //$("#tela").hide();
}
</script>
```

html:

```
    <div id="tela">

   <div id="aviso">
      <h2>ATENÇÃO</h2>
      <p>ESTE SITE (ELOJOBMAX.COM.BR) NÃO POSSUI QUALQUER TIPO DE VÍNCULO E/OU AGREGAÇÃO COM A RIOT GAMES E SUAS MARCAS, BEM COMO SEUS RESPECTIVOS WEBSITES.</p>
        <input class="btleave"type="button" value="SAIR DO SITE" onclick="fechaAviso()" />
      <input class="btjoin" type="button" value="ESTOU CIENTE E CONCORDO" onclick="fechaAviso()" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloca o script que abre a modal.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo já botei bro.

Comment: ali tem o que fecha...

Comment: Só tem isso na script

Comment: Ele aparece quando carrega a pagina .

Comment: Não é um modal button .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma `$_SESSION` para saber se modal já foi aberta. Quando o usuário sair do <s>site</s> **navegador**, a SESSION expira.

Pode fazer assim, mostrando a modal apenas se a SESSION não foi definida:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["modal"])){
   $_SESSION["modal"] = true;
?>
<div id="tela">
   <div id="aviso">
      <h2>ATENÇÃO</h2>
      <p>ESTE SITE (ELOJOBMAX.COM.BR) NÃO POSSUI QUALQUER TIPO DE VÍNCULO E/OU AGREGAÇÃO COM A RIOT GAMES E SUAS MARCAS, BEM COMO SEUS RESPECTIVOS WEBSITES.</p>
        <input class="btleave"type="button" value="SAIR DO SITE" onclick="fechaAviso()" />
      <input class="btjoin" type="button" value="ESTOU CIENTE E CONCORDO" onclick="fechaAviso()" />
   </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Para habilitar o uso da SESSION, não esqueça de colocar no início da página (antes da tag `<html>`):

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

**Por que `session_start();` no início da página?**

Porque futuramente você pode ter que trabalhar com SESSION no `<header>`, e então a SESSION vai estar habilitada em todo o documento.

Comment: O codigo fica antes da tag html?

Comment: @Felipe só o session_start();. O da modal é no mesmo lugar da modal

Comment: mas isso resolveria se a pessoa mudar pra duvidas.php e na pagina duvidas.php clicar em index.php irá aparecer dnv?

Comment: @Felipe Não. Só vai aparecer de novo se a Session expirar

Comment: mt obrigado mano !

Comment: <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["modal"])){
   $_SESSION["modal"] = true;
?>
 só essa parte aqui fica antes do html

Comment: a div do modal fica depois não é isso?

Comment: eu fiquei meio confuso por causa desse último php q vc colocou

Comment: @Felipe esse ultimo php eh para iniciar a session na pagina, soh isso

Comment: então esse php q está separado eu boto em baixo da div ou no final da page?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71372/discussion-between-felipe-and-dvd).

Comment: Quando vi essa pergunta pela primeira vez, não tinha tag PHP e nem respostas. Mas me diga, a sessão expira quando o usuário sair do site ou quando fechar o navegador? acho que estou vendo coisas kkk

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Verdade. O correto é quando fecha o navegador.

Comment: Entonces, faça a devida correção na resposta sob pena de ganhar um -1

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Já mudei. Eu trabalho muito com Session, na hora de escrever escrevi errado. Valeu.

Comment: eu tentei adicionar esse codigo antes do html e criar uma div logo após o body aparecue porém todo estranho, e não funciona ao clicar ela e ir para outra pagina e voltar novamente aparece.

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma sessão que expira quando o navegador for fechado

> Coloque esse PHP no início da sua pagina

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

> Preferencialmente coloque o código abaixo antes da tag de fechamento body da sua página

```
<!-- inicio modal -->
<?php
 if ((!isset($_SESSION['visitada']))&&(empty($_SESSION['visitada']))){
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="tela">
          <div id="aviso">
            <h2>ATENÇÃO</h2>
            <p>ESTE SITE (ELOJOBMAX.COM.BR) NÃO POSSUI QUALQUER TIPO DE VÍNCULO E/OU AGREGAÇÃO COM A RIOT GAMES E SUAS MARCAS, BEM COMO SEUS RESPECTIVOS WEBSITES.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">SAIR DO SITE</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">ESTOU CIENTE E CONCORDO</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
</script>';

<?php 
    $_SESSION['visitada'] = "visitada";         
}
?>
<!-- fim modal -->
```

Comment: Eu boto esse seção antes do html, e crio uma div no body?

Comment: obrigado @leo .

Comment: eu tentei adicionar esse codigo antes do html e criar uma div logo após o body aparecue porém todo estranho, e não funciona ao clicar ela e ir para outra pagina e voltar novamente aparece.